# In Clojure, Can You Add an Item to a Second to Last List?

Tags: clojure

```
 (defn my-function
   [all]                   ; Assume all = '((I am) (A Fan) (Of) Yours)
 )
```

Is there a way to take the last element of all (which is *Yours*) and store it into the second to last collection so that:

```
 user->          (my-function '((I am) (A Fan) (of) Yours)  )
 Output ->       ((I am) (A Fan) (Of Yours)
```

I am unsure if there is any specific built-in function. Here is some psuedocode to what I'm thinking:

```
 (defn my-function
   [all]                   

  (cons (last input) (second to last input)

 )
```

Assume input *all* could be of any length with any variables.

Comment: You're posting quite a few related questions on Stack Overflow that would probably be easier to discuss and answer in an interactive context. You could join the Clojurians Slack and ask in the #beginners channel where folks would be happy to help you. Sign up at http://clojurians.net for https://clojurians.slack.com -- folks are very friendly in the #beginners channel!

Comment: I second what Sean Corfield said. Lots of happy nice people willing to help in the Clojurians Slack.

Comment: Why is `Of` changing it's case?  I assume this is a typo?  So you want to drop the last element and append it on the (new) last element (like slurp in paredit)?

Comment: is this the same person with nickname noobprogrammer ? from the comment style and variable naming convention , it looks so

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `drop-last` `take-last` and `concat` you can implement my-function as follows:

```
(defn my-function [all]
  (let [start (drop-last 2 all)      ; start=(I am) (A Fan)
        [a b] (take-last 2 all)      ; a=(of) b=Yours
        new-end (concat a (list b))] ; new-end=(of Yours)
    (concat start (list new-end))))
```